# How to design Bigchaindb data store(schema)?

Tags: ipfs, bigchaindb

I’m building a poc with BDB, and I’m not sure if BDB will help me,

I’m looking at building something where the users could upload some set of docs, one transaction = 1 file, and this transaction will be viewed by the user’s followers and will collaborate on the file i.e like comment on it or perform some other operations on it. I’m aware that the first upload of the file is one CREATE transaction, signed with that user(say X)’s private key.

The other user(User Y) viewing this file, and have added a comment on it. Now this adding of comment should be CREATE operation and then a transfer operation to the User X’s file? —> This is something that I’m not aware if this is a right way.

One file should have all the operations performed on it via metadata in the transaction.

How do i achieve this? Any help will be very helpful.